# how do i add bootstrap image inside a mvc actionlink syntax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller

I'm having following code for a group button

```
<div ><span class="font-icon-group">
@Html.ActionLink("Group button", "Index", "Groups",null ,new {@class="btn", @id="A" })
</div>
```

but this is wrong as font-icon-group is coming outside Group button.

How can i take it inside button please guide me (mvc syntax code need a change -above code).

with plain html it is working fine code for html is following :

```
<div>
<a class="btn" href="#" id="A1"><span class="font-icon-group"></span> All Groups</a></div>
```

please guide to change syntax in mvc.

Comment: what is ***font-icon-group*** ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Url.Action` and format the HTML however you want.

```
<div>
  <a class="btn" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Groups")" id="A1">
    <span class="font-icon-group"></span> All Groups
  </a>
</div>
```

I prefer to use partial views and templates instead of HTML-generating helpers, especially when working within a framework like Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Regular MVC Html Helpers do not support html in them. You'd have to write a custom Html Helper.

[TwitterBootstrapMVC](https://www.twitterbootstrapmvc.com/) has support for this. You'd write something like this:

```
@Html.Bootstrap().ActionLink("<span class='font-icon-group'></span> All Groups", "Index", "Groups").Id("A")
```